# What is the difference between the builder design pattern and using classes that inherit from other?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, builder

Recently I'm studying design patterns and I've been seeing a pattern called builder that in theory is supposed to encapsulate the complexity of a class, and this is the example I've been practicing:

```
class ExampleBuilder
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Kitchen kit = new Kitchen();

        // One pizza 
        kit.NextPizza(new FourCheeseBuilder("Family"));
        kit.PreparePizza();
        var FourCheesePizza = kit.PizzaComplete;

        // Another pizza
        kit.NextPizza(new HawaiianBuilder("Small"));
        kit.PreparePizza();
        var HawaiianPizza = kit.PizzaComplete;
    }
}

// Final Product
public class Pizza
{
    public string Dough { get; set; }
    public string Sauce { get; set; }
    public string Stuff { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public bool BeenFolded { get; set; }

    public Pizza()
    {

    }

    public Pizza(string Size, string Dough, string Sauce, string Stuff, bool BeenFolded) : this()
    {
        this.Size = Size;
        this.Dough = Dough;
        this.Sauce = Sauce;
        this.Stuff = Stuff;
        this.BeenFolded = BeenFolded;
    }
}

// Builder
public abstract class PizzaBuilder
{
    // Protected para que las clases que implementen puedan acceder
    protected Pizza _pizza;
    public string Size { get; set; }

    public Pizza ObtainPizza() { return _pizza; }



    // Un paso para cada una de las propiedades
    public virtual void PrepareDough()
    {

    }

    public virtual void PrepareSauce()
    {

    }

    public virtual void PrepareStuff()
    {

    }

    public virtual void FoldPizza()
    {

    }

}

// BuilderConcrete
public class HawaiianBuilder : PizzaBuilder
{
    public HawaiianBuilder(string size)
    {
        _pizza = new Pizza
        {
            Size = size
        };
    }
    public override void PrepareDough()
    {
        _pizza.Dough = "Soft";
    }

    public override void PrepareSauce()
    {
        _pizza.Sauce = "Sweet";
    }

    public override void PrepareStuff()
    {
        _pizza.Stuff = "pineapple, tomato, ham";
    }
}

// Another BuilderConcrete
public class FourCheeseBuilder : PizzaBuilder
{
    public FourCheeseBuilder(string size)
    {
        _pizza = new Pizza
        {
            Size = size
        };
    }
    public override void PrepareDough()
    {
        _pizza.Dough = "Coocked";
    }

    public override void PrepareSauce()
    {
        _pizza.Sauce = "Roquefort";
    }

    public override void PrepareStuff()
    {
        _pizza.Stuff = "mozzarela, gorgonzola, parmesano, ricotta";
    }
}

// Director
public class Kitchen
{
    private PizzaBuilder _pizzaBuilder;

    public void NextPizza(PizzaBuilder pizzaBuilder)
    {
        _pizzaBuilder = pizzaBuilder;
    }

    public void PreparePizza()
    {
        _pizzaBuilder.PrepareDough();
        _pizzaBuilder.PrepareSauce();
        _pizzaBuilder.PrepareStuff();
    }

    public Pizza PizzaComplete
    {
        get { return _pizzaBuilder.ObtainPizza(); }

    }
}
```

I had to do all that stuff to define two types of different classes, and I don't understand why is these better than do this:

```
 class ExampleBuilder
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //One Pizza
        var FourCheesePizza2 = new FourCheese2("Family");

        //Another Pizza
        var HawaiianPizza2 = new HawaiianPizza2("Small");
    }
}

// Final product
public abstract class Pizza2
{
    public string Dough { get; set; }
    public string Sauce { get; set; }
    public string Stuff { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public bool BeenFolded { get; set; }

    public Pizza2()
    {

    }

    public Pizza2(string Size, string Dough, string Sauce, string Stuff, bool BeenFolded) : this()
    {
        this.Size = Size;
        this.Dough = Dough;
        this.Sauce = Sauce;
        this.Stuff = Stuff;
        this.BeenFolded = BeenFolded;
    }
}

public class HawaiianPizza2 : Pizza2
{
    public HawaiianPizza2(string size)
    {
        Size = size;
        Dough = "Soft";
        Sauce = "Sweet";
        Stuff = "pineapple, tomato, ham";
        BeenFolded = false;
    }
}

public class FourCheese2 : Pizza2
{
    public FourCheese2(string size)
    {
        Size = size;
        Dough = "Coocked";
        Sauce = "Roquefort";
        Stuff = "mozzarela, gorgonzola, parmesano, ricotta";
        BeenFolded = true;
    }
}
```

**I get the same result but occupying much less lines of code, and that's why I don't know what the pattern builder is really for.**

Comment: * Builder Pattern (Sample 1)-Having a builder is use to make it for the Kitchen to prepare and cook it. * Without Builder Pattern (Sample 2) - On this sample try incorporate a Kitchen here wherein it will handle the preparation and cooking of the pizza. Without it you just prepared the pizza but nothing else. But it's really differ based on what specs of the application is. Both sample you gave is a good practice. Only specs will tell when to use either of the two. Happy coding!

Comment: Mmm, so the pattern builder serves to separate the declaration, from the construction of the object, in case it is required to further complicate the construction part. I think I more or less understand it better, thanks :)